# How to add Game Object like direction light in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am a newer with Unity. Now I am developing a Unity 3D Game in my pc and there are so many problems for me to add Game Object and control them. Who can help me how to add direction light on Screen and control the property of the Game Object?

I've tried to add direction light on Screen and it was succeed but I can't control the property of Direction light. But I don't know why I can't control the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place some objects on the scene that cast a shadow (for example a cube) and try to rotate the directional light. If the scene changes, then everything is working correctly.

[image]